# In mysql:how to display all column with distinct for one column

Tags: mysql

I want to display the `column3 = 'ffff-jhj-01'` with distinct values from column1.

```
Select distinct(name),phone,phone_id 
FROM `calldetails` 
where phone_id='ffff-jhj-01'
```

I have tried above query but it displays only `column3 = 'ffff-jhj-01'` not distinct of name.

Comment: Please show us some sample data and the expected output from that sample data. Ideally prepared on http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Remove `column2` and u will get distinct values!

Comment: i want to display all the column.

Comment: Which result for column 2 do you want?

Comment: column 2 is a phone number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all columns with the distinct clause then try this query

```
Select distinct(name),phone,phone_id FROM `calldetails` 
where 
phone_id='ffff-jhj-01' 
GROUP BY name
```

Group by will give you distinct first column, but remember you will not get distinct data for column two.

For this case you don't even need the distinct clause you can get same output with Group by alone, like

```
Select name,phone,phone_id FROM `calldetails` 
where phone_id='ffff-jhj-01' 
Group by name
```

output of both queries will be as follows

[image]

whereas if you go without Group by,

```
Select distinct(name),phone,phone_id FROM `calldetails` 
where 
phone_id='ffff-jhj-01'
```

then output will be as follows

[image]

Moreover you can get all the variants details of phone,i.e. column 2 with the following query

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT( phone ) , phone_id
FROM  `calldetails` 
WHERE phone_id =  'ffff-jhj-01'
GROUP BY name
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

[image]

But the phone field should be a text/varchar field

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Select distinct(name),phone,phone_id FROM `calldetails` where phone_id='ffff-jhj-01'
```